# How to get the image extension in laravel livewiew when uploading a photo

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How to get the image extension in laravel livewiew when uploading a photo

I have created a livewire component and want to upload a image in /uploads folders, but enable save the image extension in file name.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Imagee;

use Livewire\Component;

class RemoveBackground extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $upload;
    public $photo;
    

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->upload = false;
        $this->photo = '';
    }

    public function updatedPhoto()
    {
        // 1. validate image
        $this->validate([
            'photo' => 'image', 
        ]);

        // 2. check the image extension or mime
        $mime = Imagee::make($this->photo->temporaryUrl())->mime();
        if ($mime == 'image/jpeg')
            $extension = '.jpg';
        elseif ($mime == 'image/png')
            $extension = '.png';
        elseif ($mime == 'image/gif')
            $extension = '.gif';
        elseif ($mime == 'image/webp')
            $extension = '.webp';
        else
            $extension = '';

            

        // 3. get the photo name
        $name = 'original-'.time(). $extension;
        
        // 4. save photo
        $this->photo->storeAs('uploads' , $name );

        
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.remove-background')->layout('layouts.app');
    }
}
```

please help me to save the image with file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Livewire uses the standard Uploaded File object, so all the same methods are available as in the main framework;

$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#other-uploaded-file-information